Firebase iOS SDK: getDocuments() call pausing the whole function and gets stuck
I have a function getStoredUser() where it gets the documents in the "users" collection where the id is equal to a userId variable and if that doesn't exist, create one.
Calling getDocuments() on the query stops the whole function's execution (probably because it doesn't return anything).
The function is not part of the main thread.
func getStoredUser() async throws -> StoredUser? {
        print("UserRepository: Get Stored User")
        let query = usersReference
            .whereField("id", isEqualTo: userId)
        do {
        let querySnapshot = try await query.getDocuments() // <-------
        print(querySnapshot)
            
        if let first = querySnapshot.documents.first {
            let document = try first.data(as: StoredUser.self)
            print("There is a document", first)
            return document
        } else {
            print("No document")
            let doc = StoredUser(id: userId, usedBefore: false, achievements: Achievement(), userID: userId)
            print(doc)
            try await createStoredUser(doc)
            return doc
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error fetching stored user:", error)
        throw error
    }
}

I am expecting to get a response of either StoredUser or nil, but it does not return anything. Breakpoints stopped the execution at line 6, but not on line 7, indicating that the getDocuments function is hanging.

Is the userid value you are looking for the document id?  If not, why not?  By making the user id the document id you don't need to query. You can just fetch the document directly.

Could you give me an example of how I could do this?
Sorry, I'm a little new to Firebase

Assuming you have structured your users collection so that the user id you are looking for is the document id, you don't need to query for it.  You can simply try and fetch the document.
I would pass the user id to the function rather than relying on a property and there is no need for the function to return an optional - It either finds a user, creates a user or throws an error
func getStoredUser(userId: String) async throws -> StoredUser {
     let userDocument = try await usersReference.document(userId).getDocument()
     if userDocument.exists {
            return try userDocument.data(as: StoredUser.self)
     }
      
     let doc = StoredUser(id: userId, usedBefore: false, achievements: Achievement(), userID: userId)
     try await createStoredUser(doc)
     return doc
}


Putting a breakpoint on line 3 of the function didn't stop execution. The getDocument() function is doing the same thing it did earlier.

Then you need to provide more information.  How do you call getStoredUser?  Do you catch and print any error it throws?  Is usersReference created correctly. Is Firestore initialised correctly?


firestore is initialized in the root of the app
i call getStoredUser() within a @MainActor class which conforms to ObservableObject
the getStoredUser() function is within a struct
usersReference is created via let usersReference = Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
i have the modules imported


Does anyone still know how to do this?
